# Dragging and Dropping Outlook emails into Python Script

Tags: python, outlook

is there any way to create a python script with a GUI that allows users to drag and drop Outlook emails into the GUI to then run a script with what I want to do with the info from the email? The expected result would be dragging an email in the interface, then pulling all the info from the email such as sender, attachments and body so that I can use that info in my script.

Trying to create a python script to automate somethings with emails but I cannot just run the script on all emails in the inbox, and I want to allow users to just drag and drop it for a good UX.

I have not found anything that would allow this. Outlook emails are in a .msg format.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Hm, it appears that .msg files are only created when outlook emails are saved. I don't think I will be able to do what I want to do but if anyone has any suggestions let me know!

Comment: if files are created on local computer then you could write script which checks if there is new file in folder and extract data from file. Systems should have method for monitoring changes in files/folders - so called [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) as your gui. It will take some work to learn, but is very flexible and deep.

Here is some starter code that will give you a list of filepaths to files that are dropped into the gui. The only issue with this code is you'll have to drag out of outlook into a directory like your desktop to create the `.msg` file, and then drag from there into your gui (dragging directly from outlook is seemingly very difficult, and I can't figure out how you would implement this. [See here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-October/010807.html))

```
import wx

class MyDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        print(f'{filenames} dropped at ({x},{y})')

        #! Do stuff with referenced filepaths

        return True


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        dt = MyDropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(dt)
        self.SetTitle('File drag and drop')
        self.Centre()


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code heavily references [this article](https://zetcode.com/wxpython/draganddrop/) by Jan Bodnar.

Hopefully this isn't too intimidating, and works for your purposes. Best of luck!